# When I try to use <rich:columns> my data table is not getting rendered

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, richfaces

I am not able to use `<rich:columns>` in my project. Following is my project config.

- Dynamic Web module - 3.0
- Java - 1.6
- JavaScript - 1.0
- JavaServer Faces - 2.0

I have the following RichFaces jar files.

- richfaces-components-api-4.3.7.jar
- richfaces-components-ui-4.3.7.jar
- richfaces-core-api-4.3.7.jar
- richfaces-core-impl-4.3.7.jar

In my Facelet I have the following code.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
  xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"
  xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
  xmlns:fn="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions">
```

When I try to use `<rich:columns>` my data table is not getting rendered.
I'm not sure where I am missing.

Comment: You forgot to show how you're using `<rich:columns>`. Now no one can answer more specifically than just pointing you to the documentation and/or example at the RichFaces site.

Comment: when I try to use `ctrl+space` I am not getting the `<rich:columns>` option. I am getting `<rich:column>` and <rich:columnGroup> only. Is there any other config I need to do.

Comment: when i checked the classes inside the jar file there is no class for rich columns. in the document they mentioned as `6.6.3.  < rich:columns > available since 3.2.0`. Which jar file i should use.

Comment: Why was you checking 3.x documentation instead of 4.x documentation? [It's indeed not available in 4.x](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/RichFacesMigrationGuide33x-4xMigration).

Comment: @BalusC I didn't check the document, I checked in my project jar file . Kindly give me the link to get the latest jar file where i can use `<rich:columns>`.